# Show that $\theta (t)=e^{it}$ is ergodic.

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. We say that $\{\theta _t:\Omega \to \Omega\}_{t\geq 0} $ is Ergodic if for all $B\in \mathcal F$ s.t. $\theta _t^{-1}(B)=B$ we have $\mathbb P(B)\in \{0,1\}.$

---

Let $\Omega $ the circle, $\mathcal F$ the Borel $\sigma -$algebra and $\mathbb P=\frac{1}{2\pi}m$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on the circle. Let $\theta _t=e^{it}$, i.e. for all $\omega \in \Omega $, $\theta _t\omega =e^{it}\omega $. Show that $\{\theta _t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is Ergodic.

I'm sure it's not difficult, but I don't really see how to do.

---

My thoughts are : if $\theta _t^{-1}(B)=B$ and $\theta _t(B)$ and $B$ are independent, then $$\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(B\cap \theta ^{-1}(B))=\mathbb P(B)\mathbb P(\theta _t^{-1}(B))=\mathbb P(B)^2,$$
and thus $\mathbb P(B)\in\{0,1\},$
what actually I don't think that $B$ and $\theta ^{-1}(B)$ are independent.

Comment: How is ergodicity defined with respect to $t$ ? Is it $\forall t, \forall B, \theta _t^{-1}(B)=B \implies \mathbb P(B)\in \{0,1\}$ ?

Comment: When $t=2\pi$, $\theta _t^{-1}(B)=B$ but nothing specific can be said about $P(B)$, isn't it ?